# How to make Page Refernce work in Lighning to reidrect to an external Url

Tags: salesforce-lightning

Using page reference and an external url is not working in lightning

There is a simple vf page with a command button and an extension attached to it, clicking on the command button should invoke the vf page pagereference method and redirect to an external page.
But it is not redirecting to the page instead it is appending an encoded version of the url and giving the error:

> this page is not available in salesforce lightning or mobile app

and a method in the controller extension

```
public PageReference OpenPage() {

   String url='https://www.amazon.com';//or any other external url

   PageReference pr = new PageReference(url);
   pr.setRedirect(true);

   return pr;
}
```

Expected: Should redirect to the external url

Actual: giving an error

Comment: Request you to share more details. Your method is working with Independent/Embedded in LE Visualforce. 

Note, OpenPage() is a method in extension.  VF Page:
`<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="TestVFBtnClkExtn">   
        <apex:form >  
            <apex:commandButton value="Amazon" action="{!OpenPage}"/>    
        </apex:form>  
    </apex:page>`

Comment: So there is a controller extension and a vf page, the VF page is holding a command button and the controller is having a page refernce method where an external url is provided which it should redirected to on clciking the button,but it is not instead it is giving the error saying "this page is not available in salesforce lightning or mobile app" with an ecoded version of the url.using comand link and target="_blank" will not do the work since there are apex.pageerror validations from the method which will not work in that case.Please let me know if this suffices else shall provide screenshots

Comment: Please share the screenshots for :
1. Shareable code - Extension, Controller, VF Page
2. Error occurred.